# Trasform 4d matrix into 3d matrix R

Tags: r

I have a 4d matrix like this

```
dim(anomalies)
[1] 361  71 157  12
```

what I would like to do is to create a  3d matrix with dimensions 361x71x1884 where the last dimension is 1884=157x12

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dim(anomalies) <- c(361, 71, 157 * 12)
```

Since you're collapsing the last two dimensions this should work fine, though make sure the result is actually what you expect.